# FFMPEG drawtext filter causing error "Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together"

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to take a large video, split it apart into smaller segments and overlay it with a specific title and frame count.  However, when I am trying to do this I am encountering the error "Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together".  Is there anyway around this?  I am not entirely knowledgable with a lot of these command options in FFMPEG.  Right now I believe I am using the copy option.

```
ffmpeg -i Full_movie.mov -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/System/Library/Fonts/Keyboard.ttf: text='TEST TITLE - %{frame_num}': start_number=1: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=white: fontsize=20: box=1: boxcolor=black: boxborderw=5","format=yuv420p" -f segment -segment_frames 123 -shortest -reset_timestamps 1 -c copy -map 0 -reset_timestamps 1 "/Users/XXXX/Desktop/Test/%03d_test40.mov"
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a file with 2 (or maybe more) streams, an audio one and a video one.
See the picture with some different possibilities of using FFmpeg's options:

[image]

1. All streams are demuxed from the input file and then directly muxed into the output file.
2. It's the same as 1, if you have only video and audio streams.
3. The video stream is
   demuxed from the input file,
   then changed with your filter,
   and then muxed into the output file.

   The audio stream is only demuxed from the input file and then muxed into the output file.

As you can see, you used options from both 1<sup>st</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> cases, which are incompatible.
The 3<sup>rd</sup> case is the appropriate one for reaching your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Change `-c copy` to `-c:a copy`. The video will have to be re-encoded if you're filtering it.

The `-shortest` is unusual when you're processing a single input, unless it has some streams longer than others.